# Value of variable changes automatically in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am coding a simple stack program for the students. the code is as below:

```
/**
 * This is a menu driven program to use stack
 * */

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int stack_size = 10;
class Stack
{
private:
    /* data */
    int top;
    int data[stack_size - 1];

public:
    Stack()
    {
        top = -1;
    }
    ~Stack() {}

    void push(int x)
    {
        if (top == stack_size-1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Stack overflow..." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            data[++top] = x;
            cout << "Item " << x << " pushed successfully..." << endl;
        }
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (top == -1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Stack underflow..." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Item poped is: " << data[top--] << endl;
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Items in the stack" << endl;
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        if (top == -1)
        {
            cout << "Stack is empty..." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                cout << data[i] << endl;
                ;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack s;
    char choice;
    int loop = 1, x;
    while (loop == 1)
    {
        cout << "Menu" << endl;
        cout << "1. Push" << endl;
        cout << "2. Pop" << endl;
        cout << "3. Display" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1':
            //push
            cout << "Enter value to push: ";
            cin >> x;
            s.push(x);
            break;
        case '2':
            //pop
            s.pop();
            break;
        case '3':
            //display
            s.display();
            break;
        case '4':
            //exit
            loop = 0;
            break;
        default:
            //invalid
            cout << "Error: Invalid Selection..." << endl;
            break;
        }
        //fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

the problem is when I push 10 Items continuously, then after the 10th element, the value of the loop variable changes automatically. e.g. If I input 10 at the 10th iteration, after the push operation, the value of the loop becomes 10, if I input 11 at the 10th iteration, the value of loop becomes 11 and the `while` loop breaks.
Please someone help me to figure out why this is happening.

Tools using vscode with mingw-64 and C/C++ extension pack and code runner extension.

Comment: `int data[stack_size - 1];` Explain the `-1` here vs. the `if(top == stack_size)` overflow check.

Comment: you are right. i have corrected that too but still the problem exists

Comment: Then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66417647/edit) the question with the change, so that everybody is looking at the same code.

Comment: code updated in push method

Comment: `if (top == stack_size-1)` This is still off by one, since the index is incremented before storing `data[++top] = x;`. When `top == stack_size-2` this is writing to `data[stack_size-1]` which overruns the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The size of data[] is 9 so there is undefined overflow error for 10th push

```
const int stack_size = 10;
class Stack
{
private:
    /* data */
    int top;
    int data[stack_size - 1]; // = data[9]
```

There are some serious issues in your logic
You are using an infinite while loop so loop variable has nothing do to with here and
As per your logic you have a fixed size array and your are giving an ability to push infinite values to it .

Comment: *What* infinite while loop? The loop condition checks a variable, and the loop body can modify it to exit.

Comment: "you have a fixed size array and your are giving an ability to push infinite values to it" - the push method checks the overflow.

Comment: why the value of variable ```x``` changes the value of the ```loop``` variable?

Comment: if (top == stack_size-1)  your array is { data[0] , ....data[8] }   top = -1 , 1st push on 0 , 9 th push on data[8]    ,   10thh push is on data[9] which is not there

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica you are right , but I am talking about loop variable in current when while condition is always true ,

Comment: "infinite push ability" is for infinite push calls you can make from your while loop without actually impacting the stack. which is less then the size you are checking with

Comment: "if (top == stack_size-1) your array is { data[0] , ....data[8] } top = -1 , 1st push on 0 , 9 th push on data[8] , 10thh push is on data[9] which is not there" verry silly mistake. Thank you all